# Google photos backup and sync

Tags: icloud

As I understand it, iCloud Photo Library works by uploading the full res photo to the cloud and keeps a smaller thumbnail lower res photo on the device. That being the case, how does google photos backup and sync work on iOS devices? How does it upload a photo I took last year when the photo on my iOS device is nothing more than a thumbnail low res photo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does iCloud Photo Library's "Optimize iPhone Storage" setting work in relation to other photo apps on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-does-icloud-photo-librarys-optimize-iphone-storage-setting-work-in-relati)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191803/using-icloud-photo-library-and-google-photos-simultaneously?rq=1

Comment: iCloud keeps full resolution everywhere unless you enable optimize on device. Then the fulls are everywhere until the space starts to get low and downsampling or offloading happens. Seems like a side question, though.